what is the necessary and sufficient condition for existence of a positive integer $n > 1$ such that $ A^n = A $ for a matrix $ A $?
Given: $A^n = A$, where $n > 1$.
This means that multiplying the matrix $A$ by itself $n-1$ times results in $A$.
Rewrite as $A^n - A = 0$, or equivalently, $A(A^{n-1} - I) = 0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Let's assume we're working over the complex numbers so that we can use the wonderful Jordan Normal Form. (We can also work over the real numbers if we allow ourselves to move into the complex realm as part of our analysis.)
If you're unfamiliar with the result, we can "almost diagonalize" any matrix $A$ as $A = PJP^{-1}$ where $P$ is invertible and $J$ is a matrix which is almost diagonal, except $1$'s directly above the diagonal are allowed in certain cases.
Diagonalization is great for working with powers, since $A^n = PJ^nP^{-1}$, and diagonal matrices are super easy to take powers of.
It turns out that for $J^n = J$ to hold, $J$ cannot have any $1$'s above the diagonal, and all of the diagonal entries must satisfy the equation $x^n - x = 0$.
So the necessary and sufficient condition is as follows for an $m \times m$ matrix:

The matrix can be diagonalized (not just put in Jordan form); that is, $A$ has $m$ linearly independent eigenvectors.
All of the (possibly complex) eigenvalues are zero or a complex root of unity.

Then we have $A^{N+1}=A$ where $N$ is some number such that every nonzero eigenvalue is an $N$th root of unity.

The Jordan canonical form need not exist over $\mathbb{R}$. A matrix has a Jordan canonical form if and only if its characteristic polynomial splits over the field. A rotation of the real plane by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ satisfies $A^5=A$, bit does not have a JCF over $\mathbb{R}$.

@ArturoMagidin But real matrices still have a complex JNF if we allow complex eigenvalues. I will edit for clarity.

If you are willing to go to an extension field, then why restrict yourself to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? You could do that over any field,

@ArturoMagidin Mostly I was just assuming from the language used in the question that the OP was most likely not dealing with other fields, and I didn't want to use the words "algebraic closure" or "splitting field" while still acknowledging that the JNF was field-dependent.
